# How do i login with a default user in keycloak-angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, keycloak

I am working on an angular application that uses [keycloak-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) package for authentication. I want to add a feature which would allow a public user to access the protected resources and for that I have thought to create a default user and use a specific url to log in with that default user and access the protected resources, but I am not able to find a way to supply login credentials and login manually rather than redirecting to the auth/realm page and ask user to login. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your client to use [direct grant](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#flows) you'll be able to get an access token with a simple POST request.

Form an Oauth perspective this is the [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) flow.

Direct grant come with several drawbacks and you might want to

- Deploy two instances of your front-end application with separate clients in order to avoid leaking your "more secured" client credentials.
- Implement [role scope mappings](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_role_scope_mappings) limitations for the "direct grant" public client.

Another easier solution would be to make public resources... public. Assuming you are using some REST API you don't have to protect all endpoints with Keycloak.
Example: with Keycloak Spring Security adapter that'd be something like `.antMatchers("/public/*").permitAll()`